# Max value in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, max

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and I have 3 tables, `x`, `y` and `z`. `y` exists to create a many-to-many relationship between `x` and `z`.

```
 x      y      z
--     --     --
id    xid     id
      zid   sort
```

All of the above fields are `int`.

I want to find the best-performing method (excluding denormalising) of finding the `z` with the highest `sort` for any `x`, and return all fields from all three tables.

Sample data:

```
x:   id
     --
      1
      2

y:  xid zid
    --- ---
      1   1
      1   2
      1   3
      2   2

z:  id sort
    -- ----
     1    5
     2   10
     3   25
```

Result set should be

```
xid zid
--- ---
  1   3
  2   2
```

Note that if more than one `z` exists with the same highest `sort` value, then I still only want one row per `x`.

Note also that in my real-world situation, there are other fields in all three tables which I will need in my result set.

Comment: I presume you're after the solution of the real world situation? I suggest you update your question with a couple of extra fields for each table, and define what you would like your result-set to look for.

Comment: Just to add to this question. Is your database design fixed or still being implemented? I find it strange that your "sort" is in the z table and not in the y table. I usually find that a many to many relation like this often has the sort for which "z" you might be interested in on the "y" table. Ignore me if I'm wrong though, it's impossible to know without context.

Comment: It is still being implemented and I agree with what you say, but in the context of what is being built, the sort is and should be on the `z` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is with a sub query. This however is only good for getting the ID of Z. If you need more/all columns from both x and z tables then this is not the best solution.

```
SELECT
    x.id,
    (
        SELECT TOP 1
            z.zid
        FROM
            y
        INNER JOIN
            z
        ON
            z.id = y.zid
        WHERE
            y.xid = x.id
        ORDER BY
            z.sort DESC
    )
FROM
    x
```

This is how you can do it and return all the data from all the tables.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    x
INNER JOIN
    y
ON
    y.xid = x.id
AND
    y.zid =
(
    SELECT TOP 1
        z2.zid
    FROM
        y y2
    INNER JOIN
        z z2
    ON
        z2.id = y2.zid
    WHERE
        y2.xid = x.id
    ORDER BY
        z2.sort DESC
)
INNER JOIN
    z
ON
    z.id = y.zid
```

Comment: I've just compared this against the solution provided by arachnid and it came out 8% faster in context for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
select xid,max(zid) as zid from y
group by xid
```

Comment: the max is meant to be on "sort" not on zid. therefore this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
select xid, zid /* columns from x; and columns from y or z taken from q */
from (select y.xid, y.zid, /* columns from y or z */
             row_number() over(partition by y.xid order by z.sort desc) r
      from y
           join z on z.id = y.zid
     ) q
     join x on x.id = q.xid
where r = 1
```

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for. I can add additional columns to the inner select and then select from them in the outer one to get all columns in all three tables.
Now I just need to know if this is the best-performing way of doing it.